# SwiftUI List with SidebarListStyle does not have Rounded Corners?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, sidebar

I am having an `Issue` with `Lists` in `SwiftUI`.

---

**Problem:** Pretty simple, I am having a `List` with `.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())` inside a `NavigationView` and the Corners are not Rounded *(see Image below)*.

---

**My Code:**

```swift
NavigationView {
    List {
        Label("Option", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle")
        Label("Option", systemImage: "tv")
        Label("Option", systemImage: "mail.stack")
    }
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    .navigationTitle("Options")
}
```

---

**Outcome:**

[image: Code Outcome]

---

**Question:** How can I accomplish the `Standard iOS 14 List Design` with Rounded Corners?

---

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that you need different style

```
 List {
      Label("Option", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle")
      Label("Option", systemImage: "tv")
      Label("Option", systemImage: "mail.stack")
 }
 .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

[image]

**Update:** using conditional list style

```
    NavigationView {
         List {
              Label("Option", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle")
              Label("Option", systemImage: "tv")
              Label("Option", systemImage: "mail.stack")
         }
         .sidebarStyle(if: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad)
         .navigationTitle("Options")
    }
```

and helper extension

```
extension List {
    @ViewBuilder
    func sidebarStyle(if flag: Bool) -> some View {
        if flag {
            self.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        } else {
            self.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. However, I need to use the SidebarListStyle since I would like to have the Sidebar on the iPad. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: We can use conditional list style depending on platform, see updated.